# How to uninstall an App from Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, applet

Word 2013 lets you install apps from the Office app store, which you can access from the `Insert` / `Apps` / `My Apps` menu. Being too curious, I did not make a proper research on this feature before installing the Merriam-Webster dictionary app.

The darn app won't launch properly, so after a few attempts, I decided to reinstall the app. To my horror, now the same app appears *twice* in the `My Apps` drop-down box. Typically to Microsoft's recent half-baked features, I could not find a way to **remove** this app from my Word 2013!

When opening the `Store`, I can only see how to further plague my Word with more apps. Even when selecting `Manage My Apps`, I can only hide the app in the online list (but not uninstall it), and even then, the two instances of the app still appear in the `My Apps` drop-box.

**How can I remove Apps from my Word 2013 installation?**